# Multiplying string by a factor in C++

Tags: c++

Is there a simple way to create a string with a repeating sequence by multiplying the string by a factor. For example in python I can do `3*'ab'` to get `ababab`.

Can I do something like this in C++? The string constructor will only take a char.

I am looking for a way to string together a sequence of strings depending on a loop counter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always overload `*`

Something like this :

```
std::string operator*(std::string const &str, size_t times)
{
    std::string res;  
    res.reserve(times * str.size());
    for (size_t i=0; i<times; ++i)
        res += str;
    return res;
}

std::string s="ab";
std::cout<<s*3<<std::endl;
```

**Edit** for *"I was hoping I didn't need to go into another for loop. –  Dochevsky"*

You can use [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) and [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<sstream>
//...
std::stringstream ss;
std::fill_n( std::ostream_iterator< const char* >( ss ),
           3, "ab" ); //Replace ss with std::cout, to output on standard output
std::string str =ss.str();
std::cout<<str;
```

Comment: I was hoping I didn't need to go into another `for` loop.